# Fence gates with two holes for lock and handle

Tags: fence, lock

I have a wooden gate and an iron gate, both have holes similar to how entry doors have for a door knob/lever and dead bolt.

[image]

I'm not sure what kind of lock sets I need to install. I thought about the quickset and other types of locks but I'm not sure how well they'd handle outdoors.

Searching online only results in fence latches, but I already have the holes in the fence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are set up for standard (door) lock-sets and that's what you should be searching for.  As far as which will perform best outside, that's a good question for a locksmith.  I wouldn't get my hopes up on the cheapies.